# The $n^\text{th}$ moment of $p(x=k)=\dfrac{pq^k}{1-q^{N+1}}$

Tags: probability-distributions

Find the $n^\text{th}$ moment of $p(x=k)=\dfrac{pq^k}{1-q^{N+1}}$, $k=0,1,2,\ldots,N$ , $0\lt p\lt 1$ and $q=1-p$.

My approach is $$M_x(t)=\sum e^{xt}\cdot p(x)=\frac{p}{1-q^{N+1}} \cdot \sum_{x=0}^N e^{tx}q^x$$

Now, $M_x^n(t)=\frac{p}{1-q^{N+1}}\cdot\sum_{x=0}^N x^ne^{tx}q^x$

Thus, $M_x^n(0)=\frac{p}{1-q^{N+1}}\cdot\sum_{x=0}^N x^nq^x$

Can we get any closed form for the expression?

Comment: Note that $\sum_{x=0}^N e^{tx}q^x = \sum_{x=0}^N (e^t q)^x$.

Comment: That said, while computing $M_X(t)$ is tractable I don't think this leads to a useful closed form for the moments. If you take $N\to\infty$ then this reduces to a geometric random variable: The moments of such are known, but are expressed in terms of the polylogarithm function. So the moments of your 'truncated' random variable are going to be even worse.

Answer (score 1):

The sum $\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^N e^{tx}q^x = \sum_{x=0}^N \big( e^t q \big)^x$ is a finite geometric series with first term $1$ and common ratio $e^tq.$ There is a closed form for the sum of a finite geometric series.

I would write $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^N e^{tk}q^k$ rather than $\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^N e^{tx}q^x$ for two reasons: You used the letter $k$ for that earlier, and it is not a good idea to use the same symbol, $x,$ to refer both to the random variable and to the index in this sum.